# OSMbonusPack Bubble title doesn't appear

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

**Context**

I am writing an app for Android, and I use OSMBonusPack to easily display markers.

I display a marker to show the user's position, got with the phone GPS, and I add a FolderOverlay to group other markers (these indicate POIs from Wikipedia, retrieved with a custom API).

I included the bonuspack_bubble.xml layout file in my projet, because I wanted to modify it to scale the "More info" button properly.

**Problem**

The problem is that the POI markers are correctly added on the map (they show the icon, and when tapped, the Info bubble shows, filled with the title and description), but the first marker indicating the user's position displays an empty Info bubble.

I have tried to remove the FolderOverlay, I tried to add the starterMarker to the same overlay as the POIs, I tried to only display the starterMarker... Nothing works.

What am I doing wrong? If you need clarification on some points or code, feel free to ask!

Thanks!

Note: using osmbonuspack v5.3 (AAR), osmdroid 4.3, Android Studio 1.2.2, and testing on a Galaxy S4 with Android 4.2.2

**Code:**

*Function in main Fragment*

```
public void drawMap(Location location, MapView map, LocationManager locationManager, LocationListener locationListener) {
...
    final GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    // Now we add a marker using osmBonusPack
    Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
    startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
    startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
    map.getOverlays().add(startMarker);

    // We can change some properties of the marker (don't forget to refresh the map !!)
    startMarker.setInfoWindow(new CustomInfoWindow(map));
    startMarker.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_place));
    startMarker.setTitle(getString(R.string.you_are_here));
    map.invalidate();
...

    // We create an Overlay Folder to store every POI, so that they are grouped in clusters
    // if there are too many of them
    RadiusMarkerClusterer poiMarkers = new RadiusMarkerClusterer(getActivity());
    Drawable clusterIconD = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.marker_cluster);
    Bitmap clusterIcon = ((BitmapDrawable)clusterIconD).getBitmap();
    poiMarkers.setIcon(clusterIcon);
    map.getOverlays().add(poiMarkers);

    // poiList is an ArrayList of custom POIs
    for (POI poi:poiList) {
        double mLat = poi.getLatitude();
        double mLong = poi.getLongitude();
        GeoPoint poiWaypoint = new GeoPoint(mLat, mLong);
        Marker marker = new Marker(map);
        marker.setPosition(poiWaypoint);
        marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        marker.setRelatedObject(poi);
        marker.setInfoWindow(new CustomInfoWindow(map));
        marker.setTitle(poi.getName());
        marker.setSnippet(poi.getSitelink());
        Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_place);
        marker.setIcon(icon);
        poiMarkers.add(marker);
    }

    map.invalidate();

}
```

*CustomInfoWindow.java*

```
public class CustomInfoWindow extends MarkerInfoWindow {
    private POI mSelectedPoi;

    public CustomInfoWindow(MapView mapView) {
        super(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, mapView);

        Button btn = (Button) (mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_moreinfo));

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mSelectedPoi.getSitelink() != null) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mSelectedPoi.getSitelink()));
                    view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Object item){
        super.onOpen(item);
        mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_moreinfo).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Marker marker = (Marker)item;
        mSelectedPoi = (POI)marker.getRelatedObject();
    }
}
```

*POI.java*

```
public class POI {

    // We define every variable returned by the WikiJourney API
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String name;
    private String sitelink;
    private String type_name;
    private int type_id;
    private int id;

    public POI(...) { }
}
```

_bonuspack_bubble.xml_

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bonuspack_bubble" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/bubble_image"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/bubble_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:maxEms="17"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Title" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/bubble_moreinfo"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_moreinfo"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="25sp"
                android:layout_height="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/bubble_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:maxEms="17"
            android:text="Description" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/bubble_subdescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:maxEms="17"
            android:text="Address"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is really surprising is that your app doesn't crash:

You set your CustomInfoWindow to the startMarker, without setting any related POI object. 
But in CustomInfoWindow.onOpen, you get the related object, and use it without testing if it's not null - and if it's really a POI. 
This can not work.

Either define a "StartInfoWindow" class, or ensure your CustomInfoWindow fully supports your startMarker.

A hint: share the same CustomInfoWindow object between all your POI markers. It is faster, and better for memory.

Comment: But what is weird, is that if I do not set an InfoWindow to the startMarker, the bubble still shows empty.
And about the shared CustomInfoWindow, should I create the object before the for loop, and then assign it to the POI markers ?

Thanks for your answer, once the app is more functional I will propose it to your "Apps using OSMBonusPack" page!